# Highcharts spiderweb - How to fix xAxis interval in case of empty data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to make fix number of xAxis interval in case of empty data.

```
Current Empty Case - https://jsfiddle.net/9c1Lxe23

With Data Current Case - https://jsfiddle.net/upt1vx8y
```

As you can see there is 3 intervals (3 borders) in case of data, but in case of empty data there is only single interval.

So I want to make fixed, should be 3 interval in all cases (also in empty data).

No of Intervals should not increase/decrease in all cases of data.

Please share a specific solution...

Answer (score 1):

First you are not looking to the `xAxis` but the `yAxis`. Now to fix the tick number you must add a max value like that :

```
yAxis: {
    gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
    lineWidth: 0,
    min: 0,
    max:50
},
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q57fyvet/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In current one there is 2 segment (3 borders). And i want to make default 5 segment 0 - 2 - 4 - 6 - 8 - 10 ?

Comment: You have to set `tickInterval = 2` and `min = 0`, `max = 10`. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gm298t04/1/